# Setting permissions for folder and all sub folders in Wix

Tags: permissions, wix, windows-installer

All of the relevant links seem to assume that I am using DirectoryRefs and CreateFolder within these. When I run heat I get a .wxs file that consists of `<Directory>` tags and `<Component>` tags but not DirectoryRefs. I'd rather not rewrite the whole 5000 line file by hand. Is there a way to edit folder permissions for these tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to rewrite the `heat` auto-generated fragment. You can reference the directories defined there with the DirectoryRef elements in another fragment.

Most likely you'd like to do the following:

First, change the ID of the root directory in a heat-generated fragment. This can be done by a `-dr <DirectoryName>` command line switch of `heat.exe`. Choose a name for the `DirectoryName`, e.g. `MY_ROOT_FOLDER`. This is necessary for a convenient reference to that directory in a `DirectoryRef` element

Next, author a special component (in a different fragment), which is to contain the permissions functionality only. Something like this:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="MY_ROOT_FOLDER">
  <Component DiskId="1" Id="Permissions" Guid="GUID-GOES-HERE">
    <Condition>...</Condition>
    <CreateFolder>
      <util:PermissionEx GenericAll="yes" User="[LOGON_ACCOUNT]" Domain="[LOGON_DOMAIN]" />
    </CreateFolder>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Finally, don't forget to include this component to a feature of your choice.

Note, that by default the `<util:PermissionEx>` element **appends** permissions to **the folder in question and all its descendants**.